# Views with negative margins get clipped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a `FrameLayout` that I want be outside of a devices window at the bottom, so it cannot be seen by the user. When the user presses something, the entire fragment that this `FrameLayout` is a part of will move up and this should expose the `FrameLayout`, since it is now in view. To do this I am setting a negative margin on the `FrameLayout` and set *clipChildren* and *clipToPadding* to false on all of its parents. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

I have tried to manually add the attributes

```
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to every possible parent view, without any luck. To be sure, I even used this method to loop over the parents and set these attributes programatically:

```
public void disableClipOnParents(View v) {
    if (v.getParent() == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) v).setClipChildren(false);
    }

    if (v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        disableClipOnParents((View) v.getParent());
    }
}
```

What could be the reason that this view gets clipped when I slide the holding fragment upwards? This is the fragment's layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/rlPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCaptureImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_shutter_selector" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="START"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` at the bottom with id *flStart* is the view that should be sitting outside of the screen then sliding in on a click event (with the top of the fragment sliding out).

Highly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Negative margins aren't supported by Android officially.  They were never supposed to work, but due to a bug in some layouts they did.  Google decided it was useful enough they never fixed the bug, but they also states that it wasn't necessarily something they always support.

The correct way to make this work is to set the height of that view to 0, then when you want it to show animate in the view by increasing its height until it reaches the full size you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this sort of thing when the top level container is a `ConstraintLayout` (instead of the `LinearLayout` you have now). In that case, you can set your hidden FrameLayout to have a constraint of `top_ToBottomOf="parent"`, which will position it off screen on the bottom, then animate it upward to show it, with something like this

```
myFrameLayout.animate().translationY(-myFrameLayout.getHeight()).setInterpolator(
        new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                // do anything you need to do once the animation is done
            }
}).setDuration(1000);
```